# Photonic CHSH Games

Tags: resource-request, photonics, nonlocal-games

How can a CHSH game be realized in a photonic circuit?

Comment: Do you mean implementing XOR games using optical quantum circuits? The circuits of XOR games are usually trivial and so I am unsure how the specific construction would inform the theory of XOR games.

Comment: @ahelwer implementing XOR games using optical quantum circuits is of interest to me. wrt informing theory, has much work been done on "continuous variable XOR games" (google returns no results) ["transfinite xor game(s)" also yields no results]

Comment: you're probably better off looking for a specific xor game. CHSH is the classic example that is implemented all over the place. For example, it's the central thing inside the E91 key distribution scheme, and in randomness expansion protocols, both of which have optical implementations.

Comment: @DaftWullie I didn't realize there was such a broad class & had figured CHSH would be used.